# Masters Research versus Undergraduate Research

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

For PhD programs, do admissions prefer Masters' research (in the case where student focuses more on research / thesis due to less course load) over undergraduate research, in general? Or are they on the same footing? The reason why I am asking is this: a master thesis contains (ideally) original results, while undergraduate research might not.

Comment: For me, an undergraduate record simply shows whether the student has done well in subjects I care about.  A good mark in an undergraduate thesis shows me he/she may do well in research; this very much depends on the supervisor and also the format of the  undergraduate thesis as some universities run it as a group work type subject.  For Master, then I would look for the quality of the thesis and whether the student has the potential to produce high quality work.  If the student demonstrates that he/she can hit the ground running, great!